# How do you read a file inside a zip file as text, not bytes?

Tags: csv, python-3.x, zip

A simple program for reading a CSV file inside a ZIP archive:

```py
import csv, sys, zipfile

zip_file    = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1])
items_file  = zip_file.open('items.csv', 'rU')
    
for row in csv.DictReader(items_file):
    pass
```

works in Python 2.7:

```
$ python2.7 test_zip_file_py3k.py ~/data.zip
$
```

but not in Python 3.2:

```
$ python3.2 test_zip_file_py3k.py ~/data.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_zip_file_py3k.py", line 8, in <module>
    for row in csv.DictReader(items_file):
    File "/somedir/python3.2/csv.py", line 109, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
    File "/somedir/python3.2/csv.py", line 96, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file 
in text mode?)
```

The `csv` module in Python 3 wants to see a text file, but `zipfile.ZipFile.open` returns a `zipfile.ZipExtFile` that is always treated as binary data.

How does one make this work in Python 3?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I just noticed that [Lennart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627954/py3k-how-do-you-read-a-file-inside-a-zip-file-as-text-not-bytes/5631786#5631786) didn't work with Python **3.1**, but it **does** work with [Python **3.2**](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2/). They've enhanced [`zipfile.ZipExtFile`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) in Python 3.2 (see [release notes](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#gzip-and-zipfile)). These changes appear to make `zipfile.ZipExtFile` work nicely with [`io.TextWrapper`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

Incidentally, it works in Python 3.1, if you uncomment the hacky lines below to monkey-patch `zipfile.ZipExtFile`, not that I would recommend this sort of hackery. I include it only to illustrate the essence of what was done in Python 3.2 to make things work nicely.

```
$ cat test_zip_file_py3k.py 
import csv, io, sys, zipfile

zip_file    = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1])
items_file  = zip_file.open('items.csv', 'rU')
# items_file.readable = lambda: True
# items_file.writable = lambda: False
# items_file.seekable = lambda: False
# items_file.read1 = items_file.read
items_file  = io.TextIOWrapper(items_file)
    
for idx, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(items_file)):
    print('Processing row {0} -- row = {1}'.format(idx, row))
```

If I had to support py3k < 3.2, then I would go with the solution in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627954/py3k-how-do-you-read-a-file-inside-a-zip-file-as-text-not-bytes/5639578#5639578).

**Update for 3.6+**

Starting w/3.6, support for `mode='U'` was removed[^1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open):

> *Changed in version 3.6:* Removed support of `mode='U'`. Use io.TextIOWrapper for reading compressed text files in universal newlines mode.

Starting w/3.8, a [Path object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.Path) was added which gives us an `open()` method that we can call like the built-in `open()` function (passing `newline=''` in the case of our CSV) and we get back an io.TextIOWrapper object the csv readers accept.  See Yuri's answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70583472).

Comment: Note that support for 'U' mode was removed in 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open

Answer (score 15):

You can wrap it in a [io.TextIOWrapper](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

```
items_file  = io.TextIOWrapper(items_file, encoding='your-encoding', newline='')
```

Should work.

Answer (score 9):

And if you just like to read a file into a string:

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('eggs.txt') as myfile:
       eggs = myfile.read().decode('UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Note this is not the equivalent of opening the file in text mode and I discovered this to my cost today, although according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html this could change in the future!

Answer (score 3):

[Lennart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627954/py3k-how-do-you-read-a-file-inside-a-zip-file-as-text-not-bytes/5631786#5631786) is on the right track (Thanks, Lennart, I voted up your answer) and it **almost** works:

```
$ cat test_zip_file_py3k.py 
import csv, io, sys, zipfile

zip_file    = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1])
items_file  = zip_file.open('items.csv', 'rU')
items_file  = io.TextIOWrapper(items_file, encoding='iso-8859-1', newline='')

for idx, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(items_file)):
    print('Processing row {0}'.format(idx))

$ python3.1 test_zip_file_py3k.py ~/data.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_zip_file_py3k.py", line 7, in <module>
    items_file  = io.TextIOWrapper(items_file, 
                                   encoding='iso-8859-1', 
                                   newline='')
AttributeError: readable
```

The problem appears to be that [io.TextWrapper](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)'s first required parameter is a **buffer**; not a file object.

This appears to work:

```
items_file  = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(items_file.read()))
```

This seems a little complex and also it seems annoying to have to read in a whole (perhaps huge) zip file into memory. Any better way?

Here it is in action:

```
$ cat test_zip_file_py3k.py 
import csv, io, sys, zipfile

zip_file    = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1])
items_file  = zip_file.open('items.csv', 'rU')
items_file  = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(items_file.read()))

for idx, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(items_file)):
    print('Processing row {0}'.format(idx))

$ python3.1 test_zip_file_py3k.py ~/data.zip
Processing row 0
Processing row 1
Processing row 2
...
Processing row 250
```

Comment: [Another answer from me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627954/py3k-how-do-you-read-a-file-inside-a-zip-file-as-text-not-bytes/5639960#5639960) describes a better way that works in Python 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Python 3.8, the zipfile module has the [Path object](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/zipfile.html#path-objects), which we can use with its open() method to get an io.TextIOWrapper object, which can be passed to the csv readers:

```py
import csv, sys, zipfile

# Give a string path to the ZIP archive, and
# the archived file to read from 
items_zipf = zipfile.Path(sys.argv[1], at='items.csv')

# Then use the open method, like you'd usually
# use the built-in open()
items_f = items_zipf.open(newline='')

# Pass the TextIO-like file to your reader as normal
for row in csv.DictReader(items_f):
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal recipe to open a zip file and read a text file inside that zip. I found the trick to be the TextIOWrapper read() method, not mentioned in any answers above (BytesIO.read() was mentioned above, but Python docs recommend TextIOWrapper).

```
import zipfile
import io

# Create the ZipFile object
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('my_zip_file.zip')

# Read a file that is inside the zip...reads it as a binary file-like object
my_file_binary = zf.open('my_text_file_inside_zip.txt')

# Convert the binary file-like object directly to text using TextIOWrapper and it's read() method
my_file_text  = io.TextIOWrapper(my_file_binary, encoding='utf-8', newline='').read()
```

I wish they kept the mode='U' parameter in the ZipFile open() method to do this same thing since that was so succinct but, alas, that is obsolete.