# Reading contents of zip file without extracting

Tags: python-3.x, zip

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

My text file (`test1.txt`) contains following two line:

```
John scored 80 in english

tim scored 75 in english
```

I have compressed this file to `test1.zip` and I am trying to read the contents with following code:

```
f = 'test1.zip'
z = zipfile.ZipFile(f, "r")
zinfo = z.namelist()
for name in zinfo:
    with z.open(name) as f1:
        fi1 = f1.readlines()
for line in fi1:
print(line)
```

But the result I am getting is

```
b'John scored 80 in english\r\n'

b'tim scored 75 in english\r\n'
```

How can I read the contents of this zip file which should give me same output as original file content that is:

```
John scored 80 in english

tim scored 75 in english
```

Comment: You are getting raw input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually are reading what exactly is in the file.

The /r/n character is the newline character in windows. The question
[Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r) goes into a bit more detail, but what it comes down to is that Windows uses /r/n as its newline.

The b' character you seeing is related to python and how it parses the file. The question [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) does a good job answering why exactly that is happening, but the documentation quoted is:

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an
>   instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only
>   contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater
>   must be expressed with escapes.

EDIT: I actually found a very similar answer you can pull from for reading without the extra characters: [py3k: How do you read a file inside a zip file as text, not bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627954/py3k-how-do-you-read-a-file-inside-a-zip-file-as-text-not-bytes?rq=1). The basic idea was you could use this:

```
items_file  = io.TextIOWrapper(items_file, encoding='your-encoding', newline='')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `print(line.decode('ascii').strip())` instead of `print(line)`