# Unable to read zipped file from url

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, zip

I am unable to open a zipped file from a web.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
url = "http://..../craft.zip"
file = urlopen(url).read()
file = BytesIO(file)
document = ZipFile(file)
content = document.read('MASTER.txt')
```

And when I try to print some data, I got a bunch of numbers. There are other txt files in that zip, and when I replace the file name in content, I got the same output. Although I read [py3k: How do you read a file inside a zip file as text, not bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627954/py3k-how-do-you-read-a-file-inside-a-zip-file-as-text-not-bytes), I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [py3k: How do you read a file inside a zip file as text, not bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627954/py3k-how-do-you-read-a-file-inside-a-zip-file-as-text-not-bytes)

Comment: According to the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read read returns plain bytes, not text. You could use TextIOWrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with method of zipfile:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

url = "http://....craft.zip"
file = urlopen(url).read()
file = BytesIO(file)
document = ZipFile(file)
content = document.open('MASTER.txt', "r")
for line in content:
        print(line)
```

This code fixed my problem and I was able to look up data in the zipfile. Read has been replaced by open.